# Store setTimeout and call it later

Tags: javascript, delay, settimeout, execution

Look at the following code:

```
var timer=setTimeout(function(){increase();}, 8);
```

This setTimeout function will be executed immediately, but I want 
it to execute later. Why?

Example:

```
function increase(i)
                 {
                  i++; if(i==100) return;
                  var timer=setTimeout(function(){increase(i);}, 8);
                  }
```

Now, I need to stop and exit this function within another function when certain thing happen:

```
if (a==b) clearTimeout(timer);
```

The thing that bothers me is that variable timer is getting assigned, whenever 
function increase runs, but it does not need to, and I believe it is bad practice. That is why I need to assign to it only once, before function run and execute it later when need arrives.

I hope you understood, and btw, those are just examples, not my code.

Comment: Just store the function somewhere and don't pass it to `setTimeout` until you're ready to start the timeout.

Comment: why not use setInterval

Comment: ^^ What joyBlanks said.

Comment: when do you want to call setTimeout() ?

Comment: setInterval is considered bad practice. @John, I want to call and terminate setTimeout at various points in my program.

Comment: Why is it considered bad practice @lluxx?

Comment: As I understood, setInterval is bad, cause it will execute before your function finishes/return (if function execution is slower than what you set as interval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the operation of one function to change the conditions of another, just declare a boolean variable within the scope of both functions and change it's value depending on a terminator function.

For example, take a look at this code:

```
var exit = false;

function increase(i) {
    if(i==100 || exit) return;
    setTimeout(function(){ increase(++i) }, 1000);
}

function terminator(a, b){
    exit = (a==b);
}

increase(0);
```

Here, if `terminator` is ever called with a pair of equal arguments like:

```
setTimeout(function(){ terminator(true, 1) }, 5000) // timeout of 5 seconds means increase will run 5 times
```

the recursive call of `setTimeout` within the `increase` function will not be reached (after 5 seconds), as the function will return before reaching that line of code.

If `terminator` is never called, or called with unequal arguments like:

```
setTimeout(function(){ terminator(true, false) }, 5000) // using setTimeout here is just arbitrary, for consistency's sake
```

`increase` will only time out once it's completed 100 recursions (in other words, after 100 seconds have elapsed)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what solves the problem. It worked. I am using it inside objects. And inside every object, instead of this.timer variable, I am using this.boolean variable. (object literals)

Comment: good stuff. remember, it's usually a good idea not to dirty the global scope with variables, so I'd generally recommend wrapping the whole thing in a self-invoking anonymous function. I can edit the answer to reflect this if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable outside of function the calls `setTimeout`, define the variable as `setTimeout` when the function is called; call `clearTimeout()` from another function with variable referencing `setTimeout` as parameter.

```js
var timer = null, // declare `timer` variable
  n = 0, // reference for `i` inside of `increase`
  i = 0,
  a = 50,
  b = 50,
  // pass `increase` to `t`, call `increase` at `setTimeout` 
  t = function(fn, i) {
    // define timer
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      fn(i)
    }, 8)
  };

function increase(i) {
  console.log(i);
  // set `n` to current value of `i` to access `i`:`n` 
  // to access `i` value outside of `t`, `increase` functions
  n = i++; 
  if (i == 100) return;
  t(increase, i); // call `t`
}

increase(i);

// do stuff outside of `t`, `increase`
setTimeout(function() {
  // clear `timer` after `200ms` if `a == b`
  if (a == b) {clearTimeout(timer)};
  alert(n)
}, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `delay` in `setTimeout` takes **millisecond** as time unit, so in your code, you set your function to be executed after 8ms, which feels like immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
function increase(i, boolean) {
  i++;
  if (i == 100) return;
  if (boolean) {
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      increase(i, true);
      console.log(i);
    }, 8);
  }
}

increase(1,true);
```

What about you put in some extra argument
to the function?